# Impact of Wonder Woman's action on the end of World War I?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, historical-accuracy, wonder-woman

In the 2017 film [*Wonder Woman*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0451279/), Diana finally kills Ares and we learn that World War I is over, but how does the killing of Ares impact World War I? Is there any parallel to this with the *real* events of World War I?

As per my limited knowledge, World War I ended with Germany's armistice after they lost power due to the toll of war.

Comment: Ares may've been the cause for war. he can influent people's minds right? so without him, people have no reason to keep the fight, (just saying, no official source or whatever ;) )

Comment: Because WWI was not a tragedy caused by complex political and economical factors, it's just the evil god Ares that corrupted the goody goody humans. Best. Plot. Ever.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4362/49).

Answer (score 6):

The Ares is the source of idea of war and inspiration to constantly do it. When Diana kill him she also kills the planted need for continuing the fight. Because, as we learn earlier, the talk about armistice were already going on so there is no outside (Ares) need to fight while at the same time people have internal need to stop killing each other.

The killing of Ares and foiling the plan to gas London was not a sole reason to stop the war but rather a removal of reason to continue it.